# GAMM4 smoothing spline for time variable

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, gam, mgcv

I am constructing a GAMM model (for the first time) to compare longitudinal slopes of cognitive performance in a Bipolar Disorder (BD) sample, compared to a control (HC) sample. The study design is referred to as an "accelerated longitudinal study" where participants across a large span of ages 25-60, are followed for 2 years (HC group) and 4 years (BD group).

Hypothesis (1) The BD group’s yearly rate of change on processing speed will be higher overall than the healthy control group, suggesting a more rapid cognitive decline in BD than seen in HC.

Here is my R code formula, which I think is a bit off:

```
RUN2 <- gamm4(BACS_SC_R ~ group + s(VISITMONTH, bs = "cc") + 
s(VISITMONTH, bs = "cc", by=group), random=~(1|SUBNUM), data=Df, REML = TRUE)
```

The `visitmonth` variable is coded as "months from first visit." Visit 1 would equal 0, and the following visits (3 per year) are coded as months elapsed from visit 1. Is a cyclic smooth correct in this case?

I plan on adding additional variables (i.e peripheral inflammation) to the model to predict individual slopes of cognitive trajectories in BD.

If you have any other suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `VISITMONTH` is over years (i.e. for a BD observation we would have `VISITMONTH` in `{0, 1, 2, ..., 48}` (for the four years)), then no, you don't want a cyclic smooth unless there is some 4-year periodicity that would mean `0` and `11` should be constrained to be the same.

The default thin plate spline `bs = 'tp'` should suffice.

I'm also assuming that there are many possible values for `VISITMONTH` as not everyone was followed up at the same monthly intervals? Otherwise you're not going to have many degrees of freedom available for the temporal smooth.

Is group coded as an **ordered** factor here? If so that's great; the `by` smooth will encode the difference between the reference level (be sure to set `HC` as the reference level) and the other level so you can see directly in the summary a test for a difference of the BD group.

It's not clear how you are dealing with the fact that HC are followed up over fewer months than the BD group. It looks like the model has `VISITMONTH` representing the full time of the study not just a winthin-year term. So how do you intend to compare the BD group with the HC group for the 2 years where the HC group are not observed?

Comment: Hi Gavin, Thank you for your response! This is certainly helpful. Regarding the VISITMONTH variable-- you're correct.. this visit number was recoded as months to capture the variability of follow-up times. For the grouping variable, I did have it set as an ordered factor-- good to know I was on the right track. :) As for your last comment, this is something I have not yet figured out how to tackle. My advisor suggested that GAMM's 'may' be able to tackle the issue of differing follow-up times between groups. Would you then suggest doing group comparison's using two years (~20-24 months) only?

Comment: With `time` as a covariate I think that's your only option, to compare the curves over the common follow-up period. You should probably estimate the curves using those periods too or you will need to be quite careful how you set up the bases etc